# How do I disallow empty commits in SourceTree?

Tags: git, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

When I try to commit a file with empty message, SourceTree (v2.6.10) will show a warning popup "Empty Commit Message".

I have checked on "Don't ask me again" in that popup. But I do not know how to revert that.

[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jqeN.png)

Please help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a GUI option for it.
But you can manually edit the the config file to show the pop-up again.
Edit the SourceTree.exe.config file in the location sourcetree is installed in.
Change:

```
<setting name="SuppressWarningOnEmptyCommit" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
</setting>
To:
<setting name="SuppressWarningOnEmptyCommit" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
</setting>
```

Comment: I have tried but it's still not working. That SourceTree.exe.config file is located at C:\Users\Sakhan\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.6.10

Comment: You gave a very good hint. I have tried to search in files for key "SuppressWarningOnEmptyCommit", then I found another config file C:\Users\Sakhan\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_ivmqpdilqbaa2qtgmt3nippbjcy22ngh\2.6.10.0\user.config. It will override settings in the basic file. Thanks a lot!